# JavaScript: check if duplicate key values exist in array of objects and remove all but most recently added object having that key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates

I'm trying to figure out how to check for duplicate values of keys between objects in the same array, then only keep the most recently added object having that value.

For example, I have an array of objects I'm trying to filter duplicates of `m_id` out of, like so:

```js
arr = [
  {id: "id-1", m_id: "1", color: "blue"},
  {id: "id-2", m_id: "1", color: "green"},
  {id: "id-3", m_id: "2", color: "red"},
  {id: "id-4", m_id: "2", color: "yellow"},
  {id: "id-5", m_id: "5", color: "purple"}
]
```

The desired result from the above example array of objects would be:

```js
arr = [
  {id: "id-2", m_id: "1", color: "green"},
  {id: "id-4", m_id: "2", color: "yellow"},
  {id: "id-5", m_id: "5", color: "purple"}
]
```

As you can see, I have a simple `id` string value that gets incremented for the collection by design. What I'm trying to do is find if a duplicate `m_id` value exists between any two objects in the array, then remove the object(s) having the *lower* of the two ids. By lower, in this case, I mean non-numeric boolean comparison of the string ids (e.g., `Boolean("id-1" < "id-2")` returns `true`).

I've tried using `Array.prototype.filter()` in combination with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in numerous floundering permutations, but I keep running into trouble when I'm looking to compare key values of object elements in the *same* array inside my `filter` when the overall collection is not in scope. I'm at a loss so far in getting the results I need.

Comment: what do you mean with *lower*?

Comment: this is a non-numeric comparison. e.g., `Boolean("id-1" < "id-2")` evaluates to `true`

Comment: is the array sorted by `m_id`?

Comment: Nope, no sorting necessary :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn it into a Map indexed by `m_id`, then take the map's values:

```
const map = new Map(
  arr.map(obj => [obj.m_id, obj])
);
const deduplicatedArr = [...map.values()];
```

(you *might* be able to use an object here, but only if the respective order of non-duplicate IDs doesn't need to be preserved - since the IDs are numeric, they'll be iterated over in ascending numeric order if they were properties of an object)

Comment: this approach just takes the last object with same `m_id`.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted as you were first.

Comment: @NinaScholz, I see what you mean, though I think their response works fine based on the terms of the problem. I'll do some further checking in real code.

Comment: @NinaScholz I believe that was the original request, filtering the array down to the most recent (last object) instance of every `m_id`.

Answer (score 1):

By having a sorted array, you could check the predecessor with the actual object and check if `m_is` is not equal.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: "id-1", m_id: "1", color: "blue" }, { id: "id-2", m_id: "1", color: "green" }, { id: "id-3", m_id: "2", color: "red" }, { id: "id-4", m_id: "2", color: "yellow" }, { id: "id-5", m_id: "5", color: "purple" }],
    result = array.filter((b, i, { [i - 1]: a }) => a?.m_id !== b.m_id);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With an unsorted array, you could check `id` as well.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: "id-1", m_id: "1", color: "blue" }, { id: "id-2", m_id: "1", color: "green" }, { id: "id-3", m_id: "2", color: "red" }, { id: "id-4", m_id: "2", color: "yellow" }, { id: "id-5", m_id: "5", color: "purple" }],
    result = Object.values(array.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r[o.m_id] || +r[o.m_id].id.split('-')[1] < +o.id.split('-')[1]) r[o.m_id] = o;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks. Your second example appears to do what's needed. That's some very impressive, beast-mode logic you've written using a compound conditional inside of `reduce` 